# In my newly installed eclipse, 3 folders are missing. Java Resource, JAX-WAS Web Service and Deployment Descriptor

Tags: eclipse

I have installed JDK, JRE, Eclipse IDE ver 2020-12 , Apachee Tomcat.
But these 3 folders Java Resource, JAX-WAS Web Service and Deployment Descriptor are missing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4fC3.png)

Comment: Do i have to install any other software like webservices or IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

Those would be extra content, not actual folders, that you have available in the **Project** Explorer view, not the **Package** Explorer.

Comment: Yes it is available in Project Exporer.Thanks for your valuable answers. Still JavaScript Resources is missing in Project Explorer. I am new for Java. Please give your expertise...thanks

Comment: That content node is no longer available as of 2020-06.

Comment: Thanks Nitind for your valuable feedback